# Pass a object** between a c++/cli wrapper method and c#

Tags: c#, c++-cli, clr

So I have a managed c++ wrapper for my native c++ code that looks like this:

```
namespace AmbitCLRWrapper {

    public ref class Render
    {
        AmbitRender::Render* nativeClass;
    public:
        Render()
        {
            nativeClass = new AmbitRender::Render();
        }
        ~Render()
        {
            this->!Render();
        }
        !Render()
        {
            delete nativeClass;
        }
        void getD3DSurface(IDirect3DSurface9** surface)
        {
            nativeClass->getD3DSurface(surface);
        }
        void** getD3DSurfaceR()
        {
            IDirect3DSurface9** surface;
            nativeClass->getD3DSurface(surface);
            return (void**)surface;
        }
    };
}
```

I can import the dll into c# just fine, and create a Render without issue doing:
    AmbitCLRWrapper.Render render = new AmbitCLRWrapper.Render();

but I cannot figure out how to use either of my bottom two methods or even if they are the right way to do it - but I'm trying to follow along using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656716(v=vs.110).aspx as a template (but I do want a wrapper, not just to pass straight from unmanaged to c#

Anyone know how to do this correctly?

```
IntPtr pSurface = render.getD3DSurfaceR(); // this line does not compile
```

It needs to be consumed like so:

```
d3dimg.SetBackBuffer(D3DResourceType.IDirect3DSurface9, pSurface);
```

Comment: You tweaked your code repeatedly until the compiler stopped telling you that you are doing it wrong.  What you ended up with is meaningless, it can never work.  You don't understand the underlying api, don't do it yourself.  Plenty of DirectX wrappers around.

Comment: All I'm really trying to do is get that pointer from my ogre app into wpf - everything else on the c++ end is tested/fine

Comment: Hint: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/12/28/508689.aspx